# Issue to vertically align text within a DIV

Tags: html, css

Hello would you know why vertical alignment (text within the 4 dark DIVs) does not work in my case despite `vertical-align: middle;` and `display: table-cell;` Thanks http://jsfiddle.net/ymE8R/1/

```
.block {
    background: red;
    width:90%;
    Height: 200px;
}
.col1, .col2, .col3, .col4 {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    background: red;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 300;
    height: 24px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Comment: You want the 4 child div's to be vertically centered in the parent div (red block)?

Comment: Because you're overriding the display value of each `.col*` by using `float: left;` - Floats automatically become block-level, and `vertical-align` doesn't apply to block level elements.

Comment: Do you mean something like: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/ymE8R/9/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add a line-height equal to the height of the div it will align as you desire.

In this case, add `line-height:24px;` to `.col1, .col2, .col3, .col4 {}` in the css.

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/CUTsS/1/).

Answer (score 1):

By floating the encapsulating divs, you've made them *block-level* elements. According to [the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height):

> On block level elements, the line-height CSS property specifies the minimal height of line boxes within the element.

Therefore, declare a `line-height` property that is as high as the encapsulating div:

```
.col1, .col2, .col3, .col4 {
    height: 24px;
    line-height: 24px;
}
```

This results in the text within these columns being centered vertically within the div:

[image]

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/ymE8R/10/).